# android:inputType, textCapWords after textCapCharacters doesnt work

Tags: android, android-edittext, input-filtering

I got one EditText and I set Input filter fist I give textCapCharacters and when soft keyboard is shown it works like it should all the input is in upper case (big letters only), then I got another EditText with input filter textCapWords and when the soft keyboard is shown the letters are still in uppercase and afret input of the first character they are still in upper case just like they got input filter of textCapCharacters even the second field got the property of textCapWords. It is acting like textCapCharacters is setting some special flag that it is not cleared with others filres.

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters" 
    />

<EditText
    android:inputType="textCapWords" 
    />
```

Comment: What emulator and/or devices are you using? What is your target? Those two attributes work as they should in my hands.

Comment: 2.3 with HTC Desire. Are you sure that they work good ? Try focus on first edittext and type ABC they should all be upper without you manually change the caps and than go to the second the "textCapWords" edittext and start typing John Smith only J and S should be upper. in my case it writes JOHN SMITH if I want small letters I have to manually change the caps the input filter does not make any changes

Comment: The IME changes to small caps in the second letter as it should. Did you try any emulator? Perhaps it's a Desire bug?

Comment: I tried on other HTC Desire and it works. I guess mine devise is the problem maybe I need to do some datafactory reset . . .

Comment: I too have this problem on my HTC Hero running 2.1 but not on my HTC One X running 4.0.4... Before buying myself the One X, the Hero was my main phone and I didn't have this issue. After buying the One X, I installed a new ROM (pretty much stock with root and a new kernel) on the Hero and this is where I started noticing this issue. Maybe something related to the ROM/kernel? I'm also using the default IME.

Comment: I do not know what cause the issue, I want my program to work same on all of the phones not just on the one I develop... But I didn't find a solution for long time so I quit :(